# Is there a way to append code to an asp.mvc section

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, sections

I have partials that get rendered as part of a complex page composition.

Some of these partials need some jQuery OnDocumentReady goodness to seed list data etc.
There can be many of these partials chosen during a render (it's very dynamic)

in my _Layout I have a section definition that looks like this

```
<script src="http://my/fav/cdn/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    @RenderSection("OnDocumentReadySection", false)
});
</script>
```

in my partials I want to write something like this

```
@section OnDocumentReadySection{
    $('#partial-1').init();
}
```

and have the result of the page render end up with something like this

```
<script src="http://my/fav/cdn/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#partial-1').init();
    $('#partial-2').init();
    $('#partial-3').init();
    $('#partial-n').init();
});
</script>
```

This is to make sure all my javascript is at the bottom of the rendered html which I am told is far more optimal.

Comment: this here outlines the thought process around js at the bottom http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: jcolebrand thanks for your commentary, I don't know how you leapt to the conclusion that I don't know the reasons for doing it from the question I asked, which was, can I append to a asp mvc section rather than replace it?

I am using ASP MVC with the Razor Engine to answer your other question, which incidentally is irrelevant given that sections are available in all flavours of MVC rendering markup. 

If you have anything else to share on the subject of including script at the bottom or top of the html I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Ohhhh, I read that as "append the script at the bottom" ... now I see. ~~ As for "appending MVC sections" what I do instead is (and I use razor, fwiw) I continuously nest my <script-include> blocks inside each other, putting each template above the next include, or around, as appropriate. Hard to describe without showing several files.

Comment: Yeah its pretty much what I was doing which is was getting really messy, the good thing about your answer is that it made me think about solving the problem with jQuery and not with Razor. So while it's not the answer to my question it's the solution to my problem. It really helped me simplify what I was doing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm good at that ;) Not answering the question I mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#partial-1').init();
    $('#partial-2').init();
    $('#partial-3').init();
    $('#partial-n').init();
});
```

You should instead assign each of them a common css class (even if you don't define a definition for it) and then do this in the head:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.classname').init();
});
```

Or if need be:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.classname').each(function(){ $(this).init(); });
});
```

Comment: OK, I need to think about this, I like the approach, it's just that my real life problem isn't as simple as my example. I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Always make the example as close as you can to real life.

Comment: Yep it worked thanks. the real life example involved a but of ajax and a bunch of selectors that would have confused the issue, I just needed to rethink how I packed all that up into what is now the init function

Comment: jcolebrand I really appreciate that you took the time to answer my question. I had one of those days where my heads was too deep in the weeds to see what turned out to be the obvious solution. I'll be able to clean up a bunch of code and organise a few things so that they make a bit more sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Aye, I need that every so often myself.